# Linked Server: MO_GLOBAL.SET_POLICY_CONTEXT('S', 83);

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a linked server (SQL Server 2008 to Oracle) and would like to know how to execute this statement before I query the data:

```
MO_GLOBAL.SET_POLICY_CONTEXT('S', 83);
```

I can query the data using this:

```
Select * from OPENQUERY (linkedservername, 'Select * from tablename')
```

But I'm not sure how to incorporate the `set_policy_context` statement.  Appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct statement:

EXECUTE('BEGIN apps.MO_GLOBAL.SET_POLICY_CONTEXT(''S'', 83); END;') at tablename;